# how to give a check constraint to a character coloumn

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can i give a check constraint to a column whose datatype is char(1)

coloumn name--->group
datatype------->char(1)

CHECK(c,s,a)

plz tell me the exact query how to insert it into sqlserver2005 while creating a table,, in which group is a column...

Thanks,
Churchill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, it seems as though you only want to allow the value c, s, or a.  If I understand correctly....

```
Create Table YourTableNameHere(
      Id Int, 
      col Char(1) 
      Constraint ConstraintNameHere Check(Col In ('c','s','a')))
```

Comment: which is called a ConstraintName

Comment: You can name your constraint anything you want.  The name of the constraint appears in the error message, so I recommend naming in something the shows what it is checking.  Like Gender_must_be_M_or_F.

Comment: CREATE TABLE LEAVES(EMPNO INT,TOLL CHAR(1)CONSTRAINT da_c_s_a CHECK(Toll In('c','s','a')),SDATE DATETIME,EDATE DATETIME,FOREIGN KEY(EMPNO) FROM EMPLOYEE(EMPNO))

Comment: Thank U G Mastros...ur query worked i had made a mistake i have corrected it and it successfully executed..thank U once more..